# How can I increase my ranged damage-per-second?

Tags: terraria

When I fight a boss, I typically use a Megashark with Chlorophyte Bullets (because I aim poorly).

What accessories and modifiers can I use to get the most damage out of this weapon and ammo?

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ranged_damage#Ranged_bonuses  And I'm not sure why it's not listed on that page, but this set is good for ranged characters too: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shroomite_armor

Comment: In general, any item that will offer +x Range (x being any number) will improve your DPS.  This should be listed when you hover over said item, just to give you an idea of what you already might have.

Comment: @PanicBomb The generic damage boosting accessories are also not listed on either of those pages. (avenger and destory emblems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the most damage out of your Megashark, you'll want to have the following:

- Unreal prefix on your Megashark (+15% damage)
- Hallowed Helmet (+15% ranged damage, +8% ranged critical)
- Adamantite Chestplate (+6% damage) or Shroomite Breastplate (+13% ranged critical)
- Hallowed Greaves (+7% damage)
- Menacing Ranger Emblem (+4% damage and +15% ranged damage)
- Menacing Avenger Emblem (+16% damage)
- Menacing Destroyer Emblem (+14% damage and +8% critical)
- Two more accessories with Menacing modifier (+4% damage per accessory, +8% damage total)

In total, this is +100% damage and +16% critical chance (with Adamantite) or +94% damage and +29% critical chance (with Shroomite).

You might, however, want to sacrifice some of this damage setup in order to have more survivability.